# binding parse error, but actually working

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am tring to make a filterable list of links. I manged to show them and filter them. So far so good, but chrome is showing an error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: link is not defined;
>   Bindings value:attr: {href:link}, text:name

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'item-template', foreach: filteredItems }"></div>
<div id="item-template">
<a data-bind="attr:{ href: link}, text: name" />
</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJLmr/)

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the console using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Knockout is trying to bind your template, change it to a script tag

http://jsfiddle.net/FJLmr/1/

```
<script id="item-template" type="text/html">
    <a data-bind="attr:{ href: link}, text: name" />
</script>
```